# Second call to setState prevents first call to setState from executing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game.  In the code below, I have a context file that is used to store the global state.  I also am showing my choices component.  When a user clicks on a button in the choices component, the setChoices method is called which should set the user choice  and cpu choice variables in the global state. Then, the cpuScore() method is ran afterwards to increment the cpu score (just to illustrate the problem).  The cpu score updates as expected, but the choice variables are not updated.  If I do not run the cpuScore method, the choice variables update as expected, but obviously not the score.

//context file

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const GameContext = createContext();

const GameContextProvider = props => {

     const [gameItems, setGameItems] = useState(
        {userChoice: null, userScore: 0, cpuChoice: null, cpuScore: 0}
    );

    const setChoices = (userChoice, cpuChoice) => {
        setGameItems({...gameItems, userChoice: userChoice, cpuChoice: cpuChoice})
    }

    const cpuScore = () => {
        setGameItems({...gameItems, cpuScore: gameItems.cpuScore + 1})
    }

    return (
        <GameContext.Provider value={{gameItems, setChoices, cpuScore}}>
            { props.children }
        </GameContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default GameContextProvider;
```

//choices component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { GameContext } from '../contexts/GameContext';
const Choices = (props) => {

    const {  setChoices, cpuScore } = useContext(GameContext);

    const getCpuChoice = () => {
        const cpuChoices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
        const randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
        const cpuDecision = cpuChoices[randomIndex];
        return cpuDecision
}

const playGame = (e) => {
    const userChoice = e.target.id;
    const cpuChoice = getCpuChoice();

    setChoices(userChoice, cpuChoice);
    cpuScore();

} 
return (
        <div>
            <h1>Make Your Selection</h1>
            <div className="choices">
                <i className="choice fas fa-hand-paper fa-10x" id="p" onClick={playGame}></i>
                <i className="choice fas fa-hand-rock fa-10x" id="r" onClick={playGame}></i>
                <i className="choice fas fa-hand-scissors fa-10x" id='s' onClick={playGame}></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

What do I need to change to set the state for both choice and score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since calls to `setState` are asynchronous, your two calls to `setState` are interfering with each other, the later one is overwriting the earlier one.

You have a few options.

1. Separate your state so that the values don't affect each other:

```
const [choices, setChoices] = useState({ user: null, cpu: null });
const [scores, setScores] = useState({ user: 0, cpu: 0);
```

Or go even further and set each of the two choices and two scores as their own state value.

2. Keep all state in one object, but update it all at once:

```
  const setChoices = (userChoice, cpuChoice) => {
    const cpuScore = gameItems.cpuScore + 1;
    setGameItems({
      ...gameItems,
      userChoice,
      cpuChoice,
      cpuScore
    });
  }
```

3. Use `useReducer`:

```
  const initialState = {
    userChoice: null,
    userScore: 0,
    cpuChoice: null,
    cpuScore: 0
  }

  const [gameItems, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_CHOICES":
          return {
            ...state,
            userChoice: action.userChoice,
            cpuChoice: action.cpuChoice
          };
        case 'UPDATE_CPU_SCORE':
          return {
            ...state,
            cpuScore: state.cpuScore + 1
          }
        default:
          return state;
      }
  }, initialState);

  const setChoices = (userChoice, cpuChoice) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CHOICES', userChoice, cpuChoice });
  };

  const cpuScore = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CPU_SCORE'})
  };
```

Comment: @Jackyef    Awesome.  This makes sense.  Just before i read this, I did some additional research and found that using the updater function instead of the object literal fixed the problem as well.  `const cpuScore = () => {
        // setGameItems({...gameItems, cpuScore: gameItems.cpuScore + 1})
        setGameItems(prevState => ({...prevState, cpuScore: prevState.cpuScore + 1}))
    }` .   Is this a bad way of doing it?

Comment: @user2954945 using functional form of setState is a **good** way of doing it when the new state depends on the current state (e.g. `+ 1`)

Comment: Yes, using the functional form is preferred in this case. However, that by itself didn’t work consistently for me when I reproduced this in a codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your thorough insights! I've accepted this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, React doesn't immediately updates after you call `setState`.

If you call `cpuScore()` right after `setChoices()`, the `cpuScore` function you are calling is still the function from the current render, not after `setChoices()` update. Because of that, `cpuScore()` will set the state again, using the spread value of `gameItems` (which is still hasn't changed because the update from setChoices hasn't kicked in) which cause the changes by `setChoices()` to be overridden.

If React always immediately updates after every `setState` call, the performance would be atrocious. What React does is it will batch multiple `setState` calls into one update, so it doesn't update the DOM repeatedly.

```
const cpuScore = () => {
    setGameItems({...gameItems, cpuScore: gameItems.cpuScore + 1})
}
```

My suggestion would be either to separate this two states, so they don't get overwritten by each other, or create a new function that handle all this updates in one place.